# Airflow BashOperator - Use different role then its pod role

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-eks, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I've tried to run the following commands as part of a bash script runs in BashOperator:

```
aws cli ls s3://bucket
aws cli cp ... ...
```

The script runs successfully, however the `aws cli` commands return error, showing that `aws cli` doesn't run with the needed permissions (as was defined in `airflow-worker-node` role)

Investigating the error:

1. I've upgraded `awscli` in the docker running the pod - to version 2.4.9 (I've understood that old version of `awscli` doesn't support access to s3 based on permission grant by `aws role`
2. I've Investigated the pod running my bash_script using the BashOperator:

- Using k9s, and D (describe) command:

  - I saw that ARN_ROLE is defined correctly
- Using k9s, and s (shell) command:

  - I saw that pod environment variables are correct.
  - `aws cli` worked with the needed permissions and can access `s3` as needed.
  - `aws sts get-caller-identity` - reported the right role (`airflow-worker-node`)

3. Running the above commands as part of the bash-script which was executed in the `BashOperator` gave me different results:

   - Running `env` showed limited amount of env variables
   - `aws cli` returned permission related error.
   - `aws sts get-caller-identity` - reported the eks role (`eks-worker-node`)

How can I grant `aws cli` in my BashOperator bash-script the needed permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing the BashOperator source code, I've noticed the following code:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/operators/bash.py

```
def get_env(self, context):
    """Builds the set of environment variables to be exposed for the bash command"""
    system_env = os.environ.copy()
    env = self.env
    if env is None:
        env = system_env
    else:
        if self.append_env:
            system_env.update(env)
            env = system_env
```

And the following documentation:

```
:param env: If env is not None, it must be a dict that defines the
    environment variables for the new process; these are used instead
    of inheriting the current process environment, which is the default
    behavior. (templated)
:type env: dict
:param append_env: If False(default) uses the environment variables passed in env params
    and does not inherit the current process environment. If True, inherits the environment variables
    from current passes and then environment variable passed by the user will either update the existing
    inherited environment variables or the new variables gets appended to it
:type append_env: bool
```

If bash operator input env variables is None, it copies the env variables of the father process.
In my case, I provided some env variables therefore it didn’t copy the env variables of the father process into the chid process - which caused the child process (the BashOperator process) to use the default arn_role of eks-worker-node.

The simple solution is to set the following flag in BashOperator(): `append_env=True` which will append all existing `env` variables to the env variables I added manually.

I've figured out that in the version I'm running (2.0.1) it isn't supported (it is supported in later versions).
As a temp solution I've add `**os.environ` - to the `BashOperator` `env` parameter:

```
return BashOperator(
    task_id="copy_data_from_mcd_s3",
    env={
        "dag_input": "{{ dag_run.conf }}",
        ......
        **os.environ,
    },
    # append_env=True,- should be supported in 2.2.0
    bash_command="utils/my_script.sh",
    dag=dag,
    retries=1,
)
```

Which solve the problem.